# Android Espresso: Selecting from the searchresults one option

Tags: android-espresso

When I type "`Ja`" in search field it shows list of search results "`Janine Happy`", "`Jasper Sad`", "`James Bond`".

How to select "`James Bond`" and click on it?

I've tried: `onData(hasToString(equalTo("James Bond"))).perform(click());`

But it gives

`android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView`

Comment: if I try onView(withText("James Bond")).perform(click()); it gives NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text:

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution        `onView(withText(name)).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).perform(click());`